# How to create doped possible structures for the calculation in VASP

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, crystallography

I want to find the doped structure of a compound. So i need to know how we can find the possible structures after substitution or interstitial doping? for example i want the possible structures for 6:120
P.S: I am new to this situation, before I studied 2D materials where the doping etc was easy. if any great mind can give me time and full details of how we can create the structures and then how we can analyze that huge number of structures. I will be in more than Thankful.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3550/24)